# Database server and public website communication

Tags: java, html, database, web, server

So, i'm getting slightly familiar with html, css and frameworks in general and i have a fair understanding of Java. However, i can only see how you can make inbuilt functions and computations with Javascript that you add to your html file. But i don't understand how it works with say a Java program on your computer that the website would fetch data and information from. Can anyone explain that? I couldn't find any good answers on the internet.

Say i want to compute the value 2+3 with Java on a server and then fetch that value and display it on the website. How would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this functionality by sending an ajax request via javascript to a java servlet on the server here is an example that I use:

Say you have a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick = 'shipProduct(1)'>Test</a>
```

When this link is clicked it will look for the corresponding javscript function, which in my case is:

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param {type} action
 * @param {type} bundleId
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function shipProduct(bundleId)
{

    $.ajax
            ({
                url: "/FlcErp-war/ShipmentServlet", //this is the name of the serverlet in your project
                type: "GET", // the type of your request
                data: _action + "=addToShipped&bundleId=" + bundleId,
                success: function (content)
                {
                    if (content.substring(0, 1) == '_')
                    {
                        alert(content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //rebuild shipment tables to show updated
                        //information about the item
                        buildShipmentQueue();
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(status);
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
}
```

What I did was have have an annotated java servlet to serve my request:

your doPost and doGet will handle your post and get requests

```
/**
 *
 * @author samo
 */
@WebServlet("/ShipmentServlet")
public class ShipmentServlet extends HttpServlet {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String _addToShipped = "addToShipped";

    private static final String _bundleId = "bundleId";

    private static final String _shipmentId = "shipmentId";

    private static final String _productId = "productId";

    private static final String _updateQueue = "updateQueue";

    private static final String _unship = "unship";

    private static final String _setInSession = "setInSession";

    private static final String _externalBundleId = "externalBundleId";

    private static final String _plywood = "P";

    private static final String _veneer = "V";

    private static final String _lumber = "L";

    private static final String _bundle = "Bundle";

    private static final String _list = "List";

    private boolean multipleActions;

    private String[] actions;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processBundleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, NamingException, CloneNotSupportedException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            this.actions = null;

            //this is where we will get the actions to process
            //if there is more than one action the string will contain
            // a comma as a delimiter
            String action = request.getParameter("_action");
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

            LoadShipmentController lsc = (LoadShipmentController) ctx.lookup("loadShipmentController");
            switch (action) {
                case _addToShipped:
                    shipProduct(request, out);
                    break;
                case _updateQueue:
                    Shipment shipment = lsc.getCurrent();
                    String type = shipment.getShipmentType();
                    String shipmentQueue = "";
                    switch (type) {
                        case _veneer:
                             shipmentQueue = lsc.getVeneerShipmentQueue();
                            break;
                        case _plywood:
                             shipmentQueue = lsc.getShipmentQueue();
                            break;
                        case _lumber:
                            shipmentQueue = lsc.getShipmentQueue();
                            break;
                    }

                    out.println(shipmentQueue);
                    break;
                case _unship:
                    unshipProduct(request, out);
                    break;

                case _setInSession:
                    String bundleId = request.getParameter(_bundleId);
                    lsc.setBundleId(bundleId);
                    break;
                case _list:
                   out.println(lsc.getBundleAndProductListString());
                    break;

                // setSessionVariable(_externalBundleId, bundleId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shipProduct(HttpServletRequest request, PrintWriter out) throws NamingException, CloneNotSupportedException {
        Integer bundleId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(_bundleId));
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        ShipmentController shipmentController = (ShipmentController) ctx.lookup("shipmentController");
        LoadShipmentController loadShipmentController = (LoadShipmentController) ctx.lookup("loadShipmentController");

        // getting the product from the bundle, because that's all we care about

        Product product = shipmentController.loadBundle(bundleId).getProduct();

        String type = product.getProductType();

        //because the way we ships differs depending on the product type I need to 
        //check first mainly for veneer shipments because their bundle count is not 
        //predetermined
        boolean loaded = false;

        switch (type) {
            case _veneer:
                loaded = loadShipmentController.loadVeneerProduct(product, bundleId);
                break;
            case _plywood:
                loaded = loadShipmentController.loadPlywoodProduct(product, bundleId);
                break;
            case _lumber:
                loaded = loadShipmentController.loadLumberProduct(product, bundleId);
                break;
        }

        if(!loaded)
        {
            out.println("_" + loadShipmentController.getErrors());
        }

    }

    public void unshipProduct(HttpServletRequest request, PrintWriter out) throws NamingException {
        Integer bundleId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(_bundle));
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

        LoadShipmentController loadShipmentController = (LoadShipmentController) ctx.lookup("loadShipmentController");


        boolean unship = loadShipmentController.unshipByBundleId(bundleId);

        if (!unship) {
            String error = loadShipmentController.getErrors();
            out.println("Error:" + error);
        }

    }

    private void setSessionVariable(String name, String value) {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute(name, value);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processBundleRequest(request, response);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ShipmentServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ShipmentServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }


}
```

Comment: Just as an FYI (for other readers), an AJAX request is **one** way of doing it but not the only way.